# asyncと値の受け取りについてわかりません

Tags: javascript, 非同期, promise

JavaScriptのAsync、Awaitについて解説している記事で以下のようなサンプルコードを見かけました。

[Async/await](https://ja.javascript.info/async-await) の冒頭部分

> ```
> async function f() {
>   return 1;
> }
>
> f().then(alert); // 1
> ```

これが以下のコードであれば「1」が表示されることが理解できます。

```
async function f() {
  return 1;
}

f().then(val => {
  alert(val);
});
```

しかしサンプルコードで

```
f().then(alert);
```

だけでも同じように「1」が表示される理由がわかりません。
「1」を受け取っているように見えないのです。

これはAsyncの仕様が関係しているのでしょうか。
それともalertの仕様に関係しているのでしょうか。

どなたかJavaScript初心者にご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

以下の MDN の記事に書いてありますが、

Promise.prototype.then()
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

その alert は "Promise が成功したときに非同期に呼び出される関数 (Function) です。この関数は 1 つの引数、 履行値 を取ります" と言うことだからと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
.thenの仕様を理解することができました。

Answer (score 1):

非同期処理には特には関係なく
例えば `map` 利用時の以下の演算と似たようなものです
(強いて言えば たぶん後者は余分な処理が加わることになるはず)

```js
const array1 = [2,-1,-3,4,-7];

const maparr1 = array1.map(Math.abs)
const maparr2 = array1.map(v => Math.abs(v))
```

---

[`Promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) の構文では
引数には関数を与えることになっています

```js
then(onFulfilled)
then(onFulfilled, onRejected)

then(
  (value) => { /* 履行ハンドラー */ },
  (reason) => { /* 拒否ハンドラー */ },
)
```

> `onFulfilled` 省略可
> `Promise` が成功したときに非同期に呼び出される関数 ([`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)) です。この関数は 1 つの引数、 履行値 を取ります。これが関数ではない場合は、内部的に、履行された値を送るための 識別 関数 (`(x) => x`) に置き換えられます。

> `onRejected` 省略可
> `Promise` が拒否されたときに非同期に呼び出される関数 ([`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)) です。この関数は 1 つの引数、 拒否理由 を取ります。これが関数ではない場合は、内部的に引数として受け取ったエラーを投げる スロワー 関数 (`(x) => { throw x; }`) に置き換えられます。

関数オブジェクト指定しても良いし, アロー関数でも構わない

Comment: 「引数には関数を与えることになっています」
そうだったのですね。それすらよくわかっていませんでした。
コメントありがとうございました。